# What movie or TV show had the first instance of heroes walking in slow motion?

Tags: first-appearance, trope

There's a trope of [heroes walking towards the camera in slow motion](https://youtu.be/B3AViHVdpbU?t=1m21s), shoulder-to-shoulder.

[image]

What was the first movie where this kind of shot was used?

Comment: Reservoir dogs?

Comment: Common wisdom says that The Right Stuff (1983) was the trope codifier. Not sure how true that is though.

Comment: From http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/PowerWalk , it is The Magnificent Seven (1960) but i haven't found the scene yet

Comment: One of the more famous movie slo-mos is the [*Chariots of Fire* title sequence](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=L-7Vu7cqB20), but it's not *exactly* what you're after (they're all *running* close together).

Comment: @TroyAndAbed A 'Power Walk' is not necessarily in slo-mo, though. I don't even think the scene from 'The Right Stuff' is in slo-mo (which is weird since it's in slo-mo whenever it's *parodied*), they're just walking casually.

Answer (score 4):

An early and highly influential example must be the Droogs' walk in slow-motion side by side toward the camera (set to Alex's voiceover and a [Rossini piece](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/La_gazza_ladra)) in Kubrick's **[A Clockwork Orange](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0066921/combined) (1971)**. Ironically, our 'heroes' are a gang of sociopaths and a vicious slow-motion fight breaks out midscene, which is juxtaposed with the classical music. This will later echo in the [*Reservoir Dogs* title sequence](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=q2Xi3ioasik), depicting another uniformly-dressed gang of criminals in a slo-mo walk set to music, which perhaps hints at their fate. Here's the *Clockwork Orange* scene (starting at 0:28):