# What's the first use of the "power walk"?

Tags: first-appearance, cinema-history, trope

I'm curious how the "[power walk](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/PowerWalk)" originated, where characters walk inline (or sometimes in a triangle with the middle furthest towards the camera) towards the camera.

[image: Monster's Inc power walk]

[image: Other power walk example]

What was the first use? Has it changed over time?

Comment: *Monsters Inc.* was referencing a scene from [The Right Stuff](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XbJH7Id_p0o) which was parodied many times (though oddly, it wasn't originally in slo-mo). BTW, [this question is kinda similar](http://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/35815/what-movie-or-tv-show-had-the-first-instance-of-heroes-walking-in-slow-motion/).

Comment: Otherwise known as the "We're Sexy and We Know It" walk.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, your link to the trope seems to indicate that it originated in [*The Seven Samurai* (1954)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0047478/), and was popularized in America in [*The Magnificent Seven* (1960)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0054047/) (which was heavily influenced by Seven Samurai).

Comment: Where in the trope does it say this? I can't find it

Comment: @ZachSaucier if you click on the 'film - live action" button on the tvtropes page.

Comment: Oh cool, I didn't know those opened

Answer (score 3):

[image]

It was a common practice in the 1930s to stage publicity photos with the cast of the film walking towards the camera, usually arm in arm. This might have been featured in the trailer, but never in the final film.  Here are Jean Harlow, Clark Gable and Myrna Loy in a photo, probably for WIFE VS. SECRETARY (1936).